# CSS margin not according parent

Tags: css, margin

I have two divs, a "**container**" and a **"content"**. If content is inside container, would fit container.

```
#container {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    background:green;
}
#content {
    display:block;
    margin:20px; /* HERE IS THE ERROR */
    background:yellow;
}
```

The top and bottom margins are not inside parent, but left and right are.

Why does this happens?

**EDIT:** [**JSFIDDLE** example:](http://jsfiddle.net/8EymN/)

Comment: margin collapsing. Use padding in the container to position the content. Or ensure the container does not have top margin set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) - the top margins of a block level elements' first child (assuming it's also block level and participates in the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow)) will always collapse with the top margin of its parent.

One way around this is to [change the display value](http://jsfiddle.net/8EymN/1/) of the child div to `inline-block`.

```
#content {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

<sup>Note: As [AndyG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975097/css-margin-not-according-parent#comment26276824_17975260) pointed out you can also prevent margin collapsing by using [padding or borders on the container div](http://jsfiddle.net/8EymN/2/) among many other ways. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) for a complete list.</sup>

Comment: One of the other ways is to add `padding: 1px;` to the container (parent) element.

Comment: That is the best way actually, I forgot that padding or borders between the parent & child also prevent collapsing. Thanks

Comment: You can add it to your answer if you like ;)

Comment: You need add _width: 100%;_ if you want use inline-block to emulate behavior as _display: block;_.

Comment: No, that will push the div out of the container, look at the padding method that @AndyG pointed out (IMO the best solution) - http://jsfiddle.net/8EymN/2/

Comment: Any of padding, border or overflow:hidden to parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do next:

- add overflow: hidden; to parent;
- add border, like this border: 1px solid transparent; to parent
- add padding to parent

  ```
  #container {
      background: green;

      border: 1px solid transparent;

      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 300px;
  }
  #content {
      background: yellow;
      display: block;
      margin: 19px; /* because 1px for parent border */
  }
  ```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/3cXys/